# How do I setup IIS 6 with anonymous access for local asp.net webforms development?

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-authentication

When I setup IIS6 to develop projects locally I have to enable "Integrated Windows Authentication" under directory security in order for my CSS & Images to show up. (Note: I have double checked that network service has rights to all directories in my web application)

However this often causes my browser to prompt me for windows login username and password when I am running the application.

Is there anyway to get around entering a windows login password all the time ?

(I am using windows xp pro 64bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is some problem with the kerberos authentication to your web site. Just disable it on your site. from the c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts directory run this command.

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/WebSite/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM"
```

Or change the authentication to anonymous. And make sure that the user in the directory security tab (IUSR_computername) has access to said directories. It is not the application pool user who access files and other resources.

Comment: ah that seems to have done it, I had to give the Iusr_computername account rights to the directory, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well it certainly is not as it's supposed to be!

You say you've double checked that **Network Service** has access to the directories. But with anonymous access, the account that needs access is the **IUSR_[machinename]** account. The account is specified under the Directory Security tab.

If all else fails, for local development you might as well grant everyone access to the directories.